# ListItem focus display issue when another ListItem is selected - using keyboard navigation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React and material-ui. I have an app I'm building where I want to be able to tab from an input field to a list and then move up and down the items with keyboard arrows.

It kind of works but when I tab to list the first `ListItem` and set it as selected it also takes on a `focusVisible` style.

Then when I move to the next item with the keyboard the `focusVisible` style remains on the first item while the selected item takes on a similar styling - which looks confusing.

I've tried everything I could to either drop this styling - `disableRipple` seemed like it might work but no luck.

I also tried forcing focus when setting selected, so that the same item is focused and selected, with refs but could not get that to work either.

I've recreated it in the codesandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w6urc?file=/demo.js

Comment: Not sure if it helps but `MenuItem` which is similar does not have this issue.

Comment: You need to play with CSS, specifically `.Mui-focusVisible` and `.Mui-selected`

Comment: I tried working with those as well but couldn't get to a solution that worked. I did not spend much time as it seemed as if it should be able to move focus to items as they are selected and/or use `disableRipple`. I will revisit again if there is no better solution.